# Я так сделал, т. к.(,) не сделал я бы этого — всё было бы-с ужаснейше

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Я так сделал, т. к.(,) не сделал я бы этого — всё было бы-с ужаснейше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант без тире рассмотрим:

*Я так сделал, т. к., (если) не сделал я бы этого, всё было бы-с ужаснейше*.

Придаточное **не сделал бы я этого** (условное) обособляется с двух сторон.

А если использовать тире, лучше так:

*Я так сделал, т. к. не сделал я бы этого — всё было бы-с ужаснейше*.

Тире заменяет местоименную часть союза ЕСЛИ..., ТО, поэтому запятыми обособлять не надо, достаточно тире.

Answer (score 1):

*Я так сделал, т. к., (если) не сделал я бы этого, всё было бы-с ужаснейше.*

**Работаем над темой.**

1. **Содержание** понятно? Вполне! Но ведь можно подобрать **более удачную** грамматическую форму.
2. Например, так:

*Я так сделал, а **не сделал бы я  этого** — всё было бы хуже.*

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

Надо работать с **корректной** грамматикой, и для заданного **содержания** нужно подобрать такую грамматику.

Рассмотрим: *Я так сделал, **так как не сделал я бы** этого...*

Как **воспринимается** на слух такое сочетание? Поэтому исправить форму было **необходимо.**